# Do we still need "Drupal Users Table Name" setting on CMS Database Integration screen?

Tags: drupal

I've got a CiviCRM 4.7.9 install running in a Drupal multisite. I have a ton of databases, named something like this:

- CiviCRM: org_dev_crm
- Drupal default site: org_dev_cms
- Drupal site 2: org_dev_cms_other
- Drupal database for tables shared across sites: org_dev_cms_shared

The users table is shared across instances in the last database, and Drupal settings.php file contains the following line:

```
$databases['default']['default']['prefix']['users'] = '`org_dev_cms_shared`.';
```

Since the `users` table is in an unusual place, I thought I'd have to tell CiviCRM about it by going to *Administer > System Settings > CMS Database Integration*. On a lark, however, I decided to test if this was necessary. I ran the user-to-contact sync (*Administer > Users and Permissions > Synchronize Users to Contacts*), and it worked just fine. If there ever was a way to test CiviCRM's ability to access Drupal's user table, I figured this was it.

So, to wrap this up:

- What is this setting used for, if not synching?
- Do we still need this setting, or has CiviCRM learned how to read Drupal config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Context**: When reading data from the CMS, one can either read directly from their database (via `DB::connect()` and `SELECT * FROM user ...`) or you can use the CMS's PHP APIs (e.g. `user_load(...)`). In one sense, reading from SQL directly is more robust (no dependency on complicated PHP code); in another sense, reading from a PHP API is more robust (because it handles all the weird edge-cases of jerry-rigged SQL schema that Drupal allows).

**Speculation**: My strong *suspicion* is that early versions of Civi (like 1.x or 2.x) relied heavily on SQL-based integration. (Witness: the installation process and `civicrm.settings.php` prominently solicit `CIVICRM_UF_DSN`), but this doesn't work well in jerry-rigged SQL schema, and it's unpleasant for Civi to be coupled to the CMS SQL, so... it was gradually killed as people fixed bugs.

**Current Reality**: I can only find one function that hits the CMS user table directly via SQL -- `CRM_Utils_System_*::authenticate()`. The details of this are a bit weird and vary by CMS:

- In Joomla, WordPress, and D8, `authenticate()` uses the CMS's PHP APIs. They don't hit SQL directly.
- In D6, `authenticate()` always queries via `DB::connect()` and SQL.
- In D7 and Backdrop, `authenticate()` sometimes queries via `DB::connect()` and SQL. The way it's written... it's hard to tell if it's ever used. From some grepping... if it is used... it's probably the CiviMail-SOAP adapter (`extern/soap.php` and `CRM/Utils/SoapServer.php`).

However, I don't believe this is a hard requirement -- considering that Joomla/WordPress/D8 don't use it. You could probably figure a patch to `CRM_Utils_System_*::authenticate()` and `CRM/Utils/SoapServer.php` which allows us to completely remove `CIVICRM_UF_DSN` and `userFrameworkUsersTableName`. The main cost would be re-testing the SOAP return-channel in each CMS.

Comment: There are 2 PRs open for review on this function in SOAP so I suspect it does not currently work right ... https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8787

Comment: Yeah, I share the general sentiment of "there-be-dragons" in this area. The PR seems to imply that `WordPress::authenticate()` works as long as you bootstrap the CMS. The overwrought bit (tying into Chris's note) is it's a bit of mess understanding which use-cases will boot the CMS. My feeling is that basically everything except `extern/open.php` and maybe `extern/url.php` should enable CMS boootstrap. (Note, though, that this is similar-but-different to making the CMS the sole entry-point.)

Comment: Thanks for both helpful answers. I marked Tim's as accepted because it had a little more detail.

Answer (score 4):

There are scripts in `extern/*.php` (like `extern/ipn.php`) which fire up CiviCRM without the CMS bootstrapped. I believe the plan is to replace them with callbacks (like `civicrm/payment/ipn/%id`) which eliminate instances where CiviCRM is bootstrapped without the CMS. ([Some links here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/14310/149), but don't think there's a JIRA issue on it?)

So: Perhaps in the few places where CiviCRM doesn't have Drupal bootstrapped, eg *new user create during PayPal IPN on successful event rego*? (I made up this case as a potential place CiviCRM might need it, and not be able to deduce from bootstrapped CMS.)